# Python SQLite removes/escapes part of regular expression pattern in user defined function

Tags: python, sqlite

I did a simple replace implementation for regular expressions in python sqlite3:

```
import sqlite3, re

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = db.cursor()
c.executescript("""
create table t2 (n REAL, v TEXT, t TEXT);
insert into t2 VALUES (6, "F", "ef");
insert into t2 VALUES (1, "A", "aa");
insert into t2 VALUES (2, "B", "be");
insert into t2 VALUES (4, "D", "de");
insert into t2 VALUES (5, "E", "ee");
insert into t2 VALUES (3, "C", "ze");
    """);
db.commit()

def preg_replace(string, pattern, replace):
    return re.sub(pattern, replace, string)

db.create_function('replace',1,preg_replace)

c = db.cursor()
# This does not do anything
c.execute("UPDATE t2 SET t=replace(t,?,?)",('e$','ee'))
db.commit()

c = db.cursor()
c.execute("select * from t2")
print c.fetchall()

// This makes 'be' to 'bee'
print preg_replace("be","e$","ee")
```

My problem is now that my UPDATE command does not replace 'e' at the end of the table entries.
If I use just 'e' as a pattern it works fine ('be' ends up as 'bee').
If I manually change 'be' in the table to 'be$', it gets modiefied to 'bee'.

However, I can replace the 'e' at the end of the string if I use the preg_replace function directly.

I do not understand why. is there some string escaping going on when the input for my user defined function goes to sqlite? Thanks a lot in advance.

PS: Running Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must tell [create_function()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function) how many parameters the function has.

Your `preg_replace` will be used if the SQL calls `replace()` with one parameter.

Comment: Well... that was easy. Works now smoothly. The single parameter was a leftover from some debugging before. Just forgot to change it. Now I feel embarrassed.I edited the script if somebody is ever interested in such implementation.